# Turn off / mock kafka-streams in QuarkusTest

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, quarkus

I could separate this functionality to the other service, but it's too small and not worth the effort.
I would like to test it somewhat contained, wrote dao mocks and so, with some effort could even be a unit, but `@QuarkusTest` makes it simpler and completer.

When running it `kafka-streams` extension makes its topology, and does no difference for this test, but still loads itself unnecessarily.

I tried to mock the provider or/and the topology.
Is there a way to disable kafka-streams completely for some profile or just a single test.

Here is the code in some abstract, i may create full example in future if this is not enough.

application.conf

```
kafka-streams:
  bootstrap-servers:localhost:9092 
  topics: ${KAFKA_DATA:data_topic}, ${KAFKA_META:meta_topic}
  application-id: ${KAFKA_STREAMS_APPLICATION_ID:meta_data}
```

StreamsImpl.java

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class StreamsImpl {


    @Inject
    MetaDataService metaDataService;

    @Produces
    public Topology buildTopology() {
        StreamsBuilder sb = new StreamsBuilder();
        sb
                .stream(appConfig.metaTopic(), Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.ByteArray()))
                .map(StreamsImpl::metaValidate)
                .to(appConfig.metaTopicValid(), Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.ByteArray()));

        Topology topology = sb.build();

        StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, MetaDataStatus>> storeBuilder =
                Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
                        Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(appConfig.stateStore()),
                        Serdes.String(),
                        new MessageLiteSerde<>(MetaDataStatus.parser())
                );

        topology.addSource(META_SOURCE, stringDeserializer, metaDeserializer,
                appConfig.metaTopic());
        topology.addSource(DATA_SOURCE, stringDeserializer, dataDeserializer,
                appConfig.dataTopic());
        topology.addProcessor(META_DATA_PROCESSOR, () -> new MetaDataProcessor(appConfig, metaDataService),
                DATA_SOURCE, META_SOURCE);
        topology.addStateStore(storeBuilder, META_DATA_PROCESSOR);

   }
}
```

in build.gradle simply

```
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-kafka-streams'
```

Comment: Please attach the code you are using to start Kafka Streams in Quarkus